# char[] and char* compatibility?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

In essence, will this code work? And before you say "Run it and see!", I just realized my cygwin didn't come with gcc and it's currently 40 minutes away from completing reinstallation. That being said:

```
char* words[1000];
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
    words[i] = NULL;

char buffer[ 1024 ];

//omit code that places "ADD splash\0" into the buffer

if(strncmp (buffer, "ADD ", 4) == 0){
            char* temp = buffer + 4;
            printf("Adding: %s", temp);
            int i = 0;
            while(words[i] != NULL) i++;
            words[i] = temp;
}
```

I'm mostly uncertain about the line `char* temp = buffer + 4`, and also whether I can assign words[i] in the manner that I am. Am I going to get type errors when I eventually try to compile this in 40 minutes?

Also-- if this works, why don't I need to use malloc() on each element of words[]? Why can I say `words[i] = temp`, instead of needing to allocate memory for words[i] the length of temp?

Comment: `char *words[1000] = {0}` will initialize it without for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not going to work, because all `words[i]` will be set to point to the same exact location of `buffer + 4`.

Your basic idea, however, is fine: you can "parcel out" a large buffer into smaller "words" by following the same basic idea. You need to make sure, however, that you do not point to intersecting areas of the buffer, and that the areas to which you point your words are null-terminated.

Finally, the idea of walking though `words[i]` to find the next `NULL` every time is suboptimal: you should store the last location to which you have written, increment it on the next write, and remove the `while(words[i] != NULL)` loop.

Comment: I understand your third paragraph, but the first portion leaves me uncertain how to proceed. I see your point-- `words[i]` will be pointing at a location in memory that may change. So how can I make a copy instead? Is `strcpy(temp,buffer+4)` valid?

Comment: @Aerovistae My understanding is that you are planning to execute `if(strncmp ...` code in a loop. If the `buffer` is allocated in the static memory (`static` or global) you do not need to copy its content or use `malloc`; if, on the other hand, it's local, you need to use `strdup` or `malloc`/`memcpy` or `strcpy` to avoid dangling references.

Answer (score 0):

`char[]` decays to `char*` in function calls and pointer arithmetic.

So from a glance, your code is valid C.

**EDIT**

As for your added question, you can do `word[i] = temp` because the types are compatible. The compiler only checks for type safety (Well, it does alot more, but in the context of why this is a syntactically valid assignment...).

Comment: Just added one more part to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it on gcc, it'll work, however unless you are using c99 compiler you need to declare i outside the for loop.

Comment: Just added one more part to my question.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the last part of your question - `words` is an `array of pointers to character strings` and writing `words[i] = temp` makes the `ith` element of that array point to the character string `temp`.

As long as you don't need to create a copy of temp to which words[i] should point, you don't need to `malloc` new memory.